# Formulário dá erro constatemente em PHP

Tags: php, formulário

Estou tentando fazer com que o formulário de minha página retorne um erro e permaneça na pagina caso nenhum campo seja preenchido.

No entanto, ele está fazendo isso mesmo que todos os campos sejam preenchidos corretamente ! Poderiam me ajudar ?

### A pagina do form:

```
    <body>
        <div class="container container-twelve">
            <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
                <h1 class="titles">Cadastro</h1>
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) {?>
                    <p><?= $_SESSION["success"] ?></p>
                <?php }?>
                <?php unset($_SESSION["success"]); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="four columns offset-by-four" id ="login">
                <?php if (isset( $_GET['erro'] )) {
                    echo '<div class="erro">';
                    echo htmlentities( $_GET['erro'] );
                    echo "</div>\n";
                } ?>
                <form action="cadastra_usuario.php"  method="post">
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                    <label for="email">Email de usuário </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Seu email para login">
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Sua senha">
                    <label for="senha2">Repita sua senha</label>
                    <input type="password" name="senha2" placeholder="Repita sua senha">
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
                </form>

                <p><a href="index.php"> << Voltar para o site</a></p>
                <p><a href="login.php"> Já tenho um cadastro >> </a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### o PHP:

```
    <?php 
        include('conecta.php');
        include('functions.php');

        $senha  = $_POST['senha'];
        $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];
        $nome   = $_POST['nome'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];

        if($senha != $senha2){
            $erro = urlencode( 'As senhas não conferem!' );
            header("Location: cadastro.php?erro=$erro");
            die();
        }

        $verifica = verificaCadastra($nome, $email, $senha);
        if( $verifica == null){
            $erro = urlencode( 'Por favor, preencha todos os campos!' );
            header("Location: cadastro.php?erro=$erro");
            die();
        }

        $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
        header("Location: login.php");
    ?>
```

### a function:

```
    function verificaCadastra($nome, $email, $senha){
            if(empty($nome)){
                $nome == null;
            }
            if(empty($email)){
                $email == null;
            }
            if(empty($senha)){
                $senha == null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema está aqui: `$verifica = verificaCadastra($nome, $email, $senha);`

Essa função não tem `return`, ou seja, mesmo que tudo funcione bem ela não vai dar nenhum retorno e a variável `$verifica` vai ter valor `NULL` mesmo. Precisa de adicionar um return na função. Note que dentro da função as variáveis `$nome`, `$senha` e `$email` não são as mesmas que fora dela. Ou seja tentar anular o valor com `$senha == null;` não vai produzir resultado fora da função...

Sugiro usar assim:

```
function verificaCadastra($nome, $email, $senha){
    if(empty($nome) || empty($email) || empty($senha)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo ! Deu perfeitamente certo !